# Current Principal not set when using Owin JwtBearerAuthentication and OAuthAuthorizationServer

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, owin, bearer-token

I have spent considerable time looking into getting my WebApi application to use the Owin authentication model as I wish to take advantage of all of the social media login methods. My immediate problem is understanding what it is that I'm doing wrong with regards to authenticating a calling user with a Bearer token set.

My Startup.Auth has been trimmed back to only the following:

```
OAuthManager.OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthManager.OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/externallogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            AccessTokenFormat = new MyJwtFormat(),
            Provider = new MyOAuthServerProvider(),
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthManager.OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtBearerOptions());
```

MyOAuthServerProvider looks like this:

```
public class OAuthServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var result = base.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
        return result;
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Question 1 is the above code all that I require when calling the service with a Bearer token set in the Authorization header? Is this the correct place for this Jwt to be placed? The token should be of the form 'Bearer ey.....' etc I believe.

Question 2 should the caller be placing the Bearer token in an 'Authorization' header on the call or some other location?

Question 3 why with the above code in place is my OAuthServerProvider never getting hit on either method? What is it that makes the Owin authentication system say 'Hold on a minute, we've got an Authorization header so I should process that' what is it that my client should be doing differently?

Is it possible that my WebApiConfig is upsetting the Owin OAuth perhaps? I have set the following:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Although I'm not sure I understand what that means...

I'm trying to test the above using an integration test which performs the following actions:

1. Creates a user
2. Logs in as that user (correctly receiving a Bearer token)
3. Makes an authenticated call with the Bearer token set on the 'Authorization' header (authentication is not set on the Current Principal, HttpContext or OwinContext)

Please ask me questions for clarification, this is costing me a lot of time! Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my WebApi configuration was upsetting the authentication process. I had neglected to include the very important line:

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType));
```

After which authentication sprung into action in the OWIN world. This problem occurred mainly because I attempted to retrofit OAuth to a pre-existing WebApi app that hadn't been set up using templates that would have done the above for me.

So just a reminder then that in your WebApi configuration include both lines:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthManager.OAuthBearerOptions.AuthenticationType));
```